# How can I use downloaded libraries with composer in pure PHP projects?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I usually use [this](https://github.com/morilog/jalali) library for my Laravel projects. I download it like this:

```
$ composer require morilog/jalali
```

And Add these lines to the `config/app.php` file of my Laravel projects:

```
'providers' => [

    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    ...
    Morilog\Jalali\JalaliServiceProvider::class,

],


'alias' => [
    ...
    'jDate' => Morilog\Jalali\Facades\jDate::class
]
```

It works and all fine.

---

Now I need to use this library in a pure PHP project. It has its own MVC structure and doesn't have `config/app.php`. I downloaded the library like always *(`composer require morilog/jalali`, and both `composer.json` file and `vendor` directory are created)*. Does anybody know how can I use it in my codes? Do I need to `require()` something? Or `use` something?

Comment: You need to use `autoload` to load it in your project using `composer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
composer require morilog/jalali
```

in your "pure PHP" project's root folder, and then

```
include "vendor/autoload.php"
```

in your root file if you use one, or in the file that you are planning to use composer libraries.

Then call the class with the full namespace as :

```
$jDate = new Morilog\Jalali\Facades\jDate
```

Comment: Do you know how can I define an alias for `Morilog\Jalali\Facades\jDate`?

Comment: `use Morilog\Jalali\Facades\jDate as jDate` then `$jDate = new jDate`;

Comment: and also look at this: http://php.net/manual/tr/function.class-alias.php

Comment: Should I use `use` **after** `include`? **before** `include`? **instead of** `include`?

Comment: after include, because the class will be available then.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `compoaser` in this case. You can add this line in your, say `index.php` file:

`require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`

And rest, you can use it the same way you're using it in `Laravel` right now.